# android- simple fade out and fade in animation for viewflipper

Tags: android, android-animation, android-viewflipper

I'm new to android and I don't know a lot about android animation . 
I've a viewflipper and I want to animate between images inside it .
This is the code :

```
 runnable = new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3000);
            imageViewFlipper.setInAnimation(fadeIn);
            imageViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(fadeOut);
            imageViewFlipper.showNext();
           }
          };
          handler = new Handler();
          handler.postDelayed(runnable, 500);
    }
```

The 2 animated file are not good , they animate very badly . 
I just need a code to fade out the front image and fade in the next image and do the same for all images inside it.

Could anyone help me out ?

thank you

Comment: try this tutorial:http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/

Answer (score 3):

Simple using Kotlin.

First, set the animations:

```
private fun setAnimations() {
    // in anim
    val inAnim = AlphaAnimation(0f, 1f)
    inAnim.duration = 600
    flipperView.inAnimation = inAnim

    // out anim
    val outAnim = AlphaAnimation(1f, 0f)
    outAnim.duration = 600
    flipperView.outAnimation = outAnim

}
```

And to flip (between two views) just call this function:

```
fun onSendClick(view: View) {
    viewFlipper.displayedChild = if(flipperView.displayedChild == 0) 1 else 0
}
```